# making dataGridView1 public

Tags: c#, datagridview

Im trying to make my dataGridView public so I can access it from another class. I attempted to do so by doing this

```
public DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
```

To test this change out, I tried populating it on Form1 with information using

```
dgv.DataSource = prevEx.ToList();
```

It would previously get filled with information  but now it doesnt get populated at all, and I'm left staring at an empty `DGV`. I know for a fact prevEx has data in it because prior to making it public, the `DGV` would get populated.

I know I'm initializing the new DGV prior to the step in which it is supposed to populate the field (its up top with all my other public variables), so thats not the problem so as of now I'm at a loss. Any help would be awesome.

To clear up some confusion here is more code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application() { DisplayAlerts = false, Visible = false };
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();

    public List<Attorney> listOfAttys = Helpers.getAttorneys();
    public static DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

    public static string fileName = null;
    public static string chatterCase = null;
    public static string userName = null;
    public static string attorneyNum = null;
    public static int batchID;
    public static string ID;
    public static DateTime dateHold;
    public static string holdDesc = null;
    public static int startingRow;
    public static string holdAccount = null;
```

---

```
    public void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbxFilename.Text = null;
        txtbxChatterCase.Text = null;
        txtbxUserName.Text = null;
        txtbxRowNum.Text = null;

        System.IO.Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files |*.xls;*.xlsx";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    fileName = txtbxFilename.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                    myStream.Close();
                    myStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                excelApp.Quit();
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        var prevEx = LegalTransactionList.previewExcel();
        dgv.DataSource = prevEx.ToList();

    }
```

Comment: I don't think this will do anything, but why is your 'click' method public?

Comment: @TheBlindSpring This program has been a learning experience for me so I was learning as I went. I must have changed it awhile ago to try and fix an error. Like I said, I didnt know anything about C# when I started this.

Comment: Oh Ok, I didn't mean to sound rude, I just am used to seeing click methods as private (I don't know why to be honest) and I thought maybe that might change something. Experimenting is always good though!

Comment: @TheBlindSpring Dont worry, it didnt come off as rude at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare with a static tag too:

```
public static DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
```

This will make it retain data between classes (globally).

In your other class call it ass such:

```
MyClassName.dgv.DataSource = prevEx.ToList();
```

Comment: With that change I'm getting an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @user2405778 you need to declare the variable first as you did in your question:

dgv = new DataGridView();

Comment: Ah I thought you wanted me to remove that, I added that back in but I'm still not getting a populated DGV.

Comment: @user2405778 did you reset your datasource? I updated my answer.

Comment: Just to make sure were on the same page, I'm currently not even trying to call it from another class at this point. I am trying to call it from Form1 so its not losing information by not retaining data between classes.

Comment: when calling dgv from the class it is declared in, you do not need to precede it with the class name. This only needs to be done when accessing it from another class.

Comment: Yep, if you're in the same class the variable is declared in simply use: dgv.DataSource = prevEx.ToList(); to populate

Comment: I think we will need to see more code if you want help.

Comment: I've updated my opening post with the code in question. @user2623678 thats exactly what I'm doing and its still not getting populated.

Comment: @TheBlindSpring I know, I'm not preceding it with the class name. I'm simply doing `dgv.DataSource = prevEx.ToList();`

Comment: @user2405778 are you receiving any errors in your code?

Comment: @user2623678 nope none. Well at least it doesnt error out when I finish running the program.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint after you instantiate var prevEx = LegalTransactionList.previewExcel(); and hover over prevEx, does it say null, or show data? That HAS to be the issue.

Comment: So if you change your DataGridView back to private or whatever it was, everything works again?

Comment: @TheBlindSpring If I replace the dgv with dataGridView1 it gets populated and everything.

Comment: @user2623678 nope its populated, if I knew how to post pictures you would see its filled with a whole bunch of data.

Comment: Column1 "2" string

  Column10 "31" string

  Column2 "6247623" string

  Column3 "5/20/2014 12:00:00 AM" string

  Column4 "45" string

  Column5 "31" string

Comment: what do you mean 'replace dgv with dataGridView1'?

Comment: @TheBlindSpring Sorry might not be explaining myself properly, if instead of `dgv.DataSource = prevEx.ToList();` I just have `dataGridView1.DataSource = prevEx.ToList();`. Essentially if I just call the actual object(?) that I added to the Form1[Design].

Comment: O0o0o0o0o0o, so in your XAML file you name it dataGridView1?

Comment: @TheBlindSpring Yeah it was the default name it came with when I added it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54671/discussion-between-theblindspring-and-user2405778).

Answer (score 0):

Make it with a static tag:

```
  public static DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
```

Assuming this control belongs to Class Foo, to access it another class simply use

```
  Foo.dgv.DataSource = prevEx.ToList();
```

If class Foo has been instantiated in the class that needs to call it i.e.

```
   Foo bar = new Foo();
```

Then you would not need the static tag and it would be accessed as such:

```
bar.dgv.DataSource = prevEx.ToList();
```

However my recomendation would be to make a public static list, and set the data source inside the same class as dgv, instead of making the dgv public and static.

And one last suggestion, try setting the dataSource to null first.

```
  dgv.DataSource = null;
  dgv.DataSource = prevEx.ToList();
```